# How to write a web browser in java

Tags: java, browser

I am an amateur java program developer and was wondering if anybody knows how to write a web browser in java if possible.

Comment: I'm sure someone does.

Comment: ...I don't think thats a beginner project

Comment: Do you want the 300-page long answer or the 500-page long answer? Either way, you won't find it here.

Comment: I would suggest you start with this book: [Javanotes](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/) by David Eck. Chapters 6 (Introduction to GUI Programming) and 13 (Advanced GUI Programming) are especially relevant. You also need to be able to render HTML, which is another huge project, although you can probably find libraries to do that.

Answer (score 4):

If you need a component to render HTML, `JEditorPane` in the `javax.swing` library is capable of doing it for basic HTML.  You could mock browser behavior by adding an input for entering a URL, getting markup, and setting it to the editor pane.  Tracking URL history and that sort of thing would be up to you, and it could be a decent project for learning a lot about Swing, event handling, concurrency, etc...

If you're looking at building your own rendering engine for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript... that's a much larger problem.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html